# jQuery-Seat-Chart remap existing seats

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery-seat-charts (https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts)  to show a map of seats (for a given hall, bus, train etc). The problem is my seat layout changes overtime and I am handling it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.some-item', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonForThisElement );

    var seatMap = [];

    for (var i = 0 ; i < obj.someAttr.Rows ; i++){
        var row = '' ;
        for (var j = 0 ; j < obj.someAttr.Cols ; j++){                  
                row += 'f';
        }
        seatMap.push(row);
    }
    var sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
        map: seatMap,
        seats: someSeatStyleObject, //doesn't matter
        naming : someNamingObject , //doesn't matter
        ... other initializations            
    });
```

So far the updating of seatMap is not working, the seat map remains the same for the first clicked item (i mean the first initialized seat map). Any idea on how to re-initialize ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to remove all data of the plugin and reinitialize again. some jquery plugins attach a data attribute with the element which needed to be removed as well as the seats and other ui objects. then call the `$('#id').seatCharts({ ... })` again.

This is how you clear existing seats and remove the attached seatChart object:

```
$('.seatCharts-row').remove();
$('.seatCharts-legendItem').remove();
$('#seat-map,#seat-map *').unbind().removeData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put it in a function? Separate it. Do you know how to override the ID and label of each seat?